# Calculation error when applying the Leibniz formula to a family of integrals?

Tags: calculus

Consider the following integral
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\check{q}-e}^{\hat{q}-e}c(\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon)d\varepsilon
\end{equation*} where $c$ is some differentiable function.

If we change the variable from $\varepsilon$ to $x=\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon$, the integral becomes

\begin{equation*}
-\int_{\hat{q}-\check{q}}^{0}c(x)dx
\end{equation*}

The value of this integral does not rely on $e$, so its derivative with respect to $e$ should be 0.
But when I tried to take the derivative using the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), I cannot get it right.
Here is how I got my result:

Replace the $\varepsilon$ in the integrand by the upper limit of integration: $c(\hat{q}-e-(\hat{q}-e))$, and multiply it by the derivative of upper limit of integration with respect to $e$: -1, I got the first term: $-c(\hat{q}-e-(\hat{q}-e))$;

Replace the $\varepsilon$ in the integrand by the lower limit of integration: $c(\hat{q}-e-(\check{q}-e))$, and multiply it by the derivative of lower limit of integration with respect to $e$: -1, and change the sign (because it is the lower limit), I got the second term: $c(\hat{q}-e-(\check{q}-e))$;

Let the integrand take the partial derivative with respect to $e$: $-c'(\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon)$, and then take the integral, I got $-\int_{\check{q}-e}^{\hat{q}-e}c'(\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon)d\varepsilon$. Using Newton-Leibniz theorem, it is equal to $-[c(\hat{q}-e-(\hat{q}-e))-c(\hat{q}-e-(\check{q}-e))]$.

So add all three terms together, I got $-2c(0)+2c(\hat{q}-\check{q})$. I think I must make some mistake in sign so the terms do not cancel out. But I double checked and failed to locate the mistake. I would appreciate it if you can help.

Edit: my mistake is in applying Newton-Leibniz theorem. The antiderivative of $c'(\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon)$ should be $-c(\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon)$ because there is a minus sign before $\varepsilon$.

Comment: It will be very difficult for anyone to tell you where you made a mistake in your calculations if you don't show us your calculations.

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes but the second formula I wrote is just to plug the terms in according to Lebnitz formula...I thought that is my calculation.

Comment: I can find the result, except for the factor 2. Are you sure about that? Can you also indicate where that integral is coming from? A source would be useful.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Could you please clarify what you meant by "can find the result, except for the factor 2"? You think the right result is $-c(0)+c(\hat{q}-\check{q})$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I obtain.

Comment: @Ypbor, that "plug the terms in" part involves multiple steps, and the "put everything together" part involves multiple steps, as well. You have shown the results you believe you would obtain from multiple steps, but have not shown the steps, themselves.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, I forgot the third term in the Leibniz formula. Which makes me wonder if you're not simply making a sign mistake, i.e. you should obtain $-c(0)+c(\hat{q}-\check{q}) - (-c(0)+c(\hat{q}-\check{q})) = 0$ ? In any case, we'll need the background info and the detailed steps of your calculation.

Comment: @CameronBuie Sorry, I think I scrolled back your edit (the wiki link), but I don't know how to modify it.

Comment: @Ypbor, if you click on the edit history link (which currently says "edited 3 mins ago" as I type this comment, scroll down to my edit, and click the "Side-by-side Markdown" button, it will show how I formatted everything.

Comment: @Raskolnikov $c$ is just a cost function, so I don't know how this background information helps...The detailed steps are added.

Comment: The mistake seems to me in your third term. There should not be an extra "-" sign after integration.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Why? The minus sign is because of the minus sign before $e$ in $\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Ypbor, see my answer. Basically, you didn't apply the Newton-Leibniz Theorem carefully enough.

Comment: Cameron Blue has answered already, but in doing the integral, you have to reuse the "-" in the substitution step that you got from taking the partial derivative, so it gets cancelled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, the Leibniz formula tells us that the derivative of $$\int_{\check{q}-e}^{\hat{q}-e} c\left(\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon\right)\,d\varepsilon$$ with respect to $e$ can be written as $$c\left(\hat{q}-e-\left(\hat{q}-e\right)\right)\cdot\frac{d}{de}\left[\hat{q}-e\right]-c\left(\hat{q}-e-\left(\check{q}-e\right)\right)\cdot\frac{d}{de}\left[\check{q}-e\right]+\int_{\check{q}-e}^{\hat{q}-e} \frac{\partial}{\partial e}\left[c\left(\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon\right)\right]\,d\varepsilon.$$ After some algebra and nothing else, the derivative can be written as $$c(0)\cdot\frac{d}{de}\left[\hat{q}-e\right]-c\left(\hat{q}-\check{q}\right)\cdot\frac{d}{de}\left[\check{q}-e\right]+\int_{\check{q}-e}^{\hat{q}-e} \frac{\partial}{\partial e}\bigl[c\left(\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon\right)\bigr]\,d\varepsilon.$$

Letting $f$ be the derivative of $c,$ and applying the Chain Rule to the integrand, the derivative we're interested in can be written as $$c(0)\cdot\frac{d}{de}\left[\hat{q}-e\right]-c\left(\hat{q}-\check{q}\right)\cdot\frac{d}{de}\left[\check{q}-e\right]+\int_{\check{q}-e}^{\hat{q}-e} f\left(\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon\right)\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial e}\left[\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon\right]\,d\varepsilon.$$

Since neither $\hat{q}$ nor $\check{q}$ varies with $e,$ then $$\frac{d}{de}\bigl[\hat{q}-e\bigr]=-1=\frac{d}{de}\bigl[\check{q}-e\bigr],$$ and similarly, since $\varepsilon$ doesn't vary with $e,$ either, then $$\frac{\partial}{\partial e}\left[\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon\right]=-1.$$ Thus, the derivative we're interested in can be written as $$-c(0)+c\left(\hat{q}-\check{q}\right)-\int_{\check{q}-e}^{\hat{q}-e} f\left(\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon\right)\,d\varepsilon.$$

Now, consider the substitution $x=\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon.$ It's clear that $x=0$ when $\varepsilon=\hat{q}-e,$ that $x=\hat{q}-\check{q}$ when $\varepsilon=\check{q}-e,$ and that $\frac{\partial\varepsilon}{\partial x}=-1,$ so $$\int_{\check{q}-e}^{\hat{q}-e} f\left(\hat{q}-e-\varepsilon\right)\,d\varepsilon=\int_{\hat{q}-\check{q}}^{0}f(x)\cdot\frac{\partial\varepsilon}{\partial x}\,dx=-\int_{\hat{q}-\check{q}}^{0}f(x)\,dx,$$ and so the derivative we're interested in can be written as $$-c(0)+c\left(\hat{q}-\check{q}\right)+\int_{\hat{q}-\check{q}}^{0} f(x)\,dx.$$ That substitution appears to be the step you either forgot or did incorrectly. At that point, recalling that $c$ is an antiderivative of $f,$ we can finally apply the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (a.k.a.: "the Newton-Leibniz Theorem") to get that $$\int_{\hat{q}-\check{q}}^{0} f(x)\,dx=c(0)-c\left(\hat{q}-\check{q}\right),$$ and so the derivative we're interested in is $0,$ after all.